# Forward to a phone number with an extension using Twilio Function

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to forward calls to a number with an extension using Twilio Functions.

I can successfully forward to a number without an extension.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  let phoneNumber = "[PHONE NUMBER HERE]";
  let callerId =  event.CallerId || null;
  let timeout = event.Timeout || null;

  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();

  let dialParams = {};
  if (callerId) {
    dialParams.callerId = callerId
  }
  if (timeout) {
    dialParams.timeout = timeout
  }

  twiml.dial(dialParams, phoneNumber);

  callback(null, twiml);
};
```

I've tried adding the extension to the phone number with a comma:

```
let phoneNumber = "5555555555,12345"
```

I've tried setting sendDigits on the dialParams:

```
dialParams.sendDigits = "12345"
```

Is this possible? I know it's probably a simple answer, but I just can't find it in the documentation. I can't find a reference to this dial function used in the forwarding sample.

Comment: try `dialParams.sendDigits = "wwwww12345"`

Comment: Hey did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You should use  that allows you to pass sendDigits as an option.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial>
        <Number sendDigits="wwww1928">
            415-123-4567
        </Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: What does the wwww do?

Comment: It adds waiting time before sending the actual digits. Sometimes the receiving IVR forces you to wait before start receiving digits. So using www you ensure those digits are received.